# How to access a shared folder using python imaplib?

Tags: python-3.x

How do you access a shared folder ? This is a shared folder which is visible to other users too. I am currently using outlook where the shared folder is visible along with my personal emails

Answer (score 3):

Following back on my question. After reading enough this seems to work.

While using imaplib and connecting to exchange in python 3

use this,

```
result, data=mail.login('personal@domain.com\shared@domain.com','personalPassword')
```

If you have access to this shared mailbox in outlook then you will be able to connect using this. Print the result if it says 'OK' then the code did work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an answer.

Posting a link here for those who are working on similar problem with a python solution.

https://medium.com/@theamazingexposure/accessing-shared-mailbox-using-exchangelib-python-f020e71a96ab

Here is the snippet:

```
from exchangelib import Credentials, Account

credentials = Credentials('Firstname.Lastname@someenterprise.com', 'Your_Password_Here')
account = Account('**shared_mail_box_name@someenterprise.com**', credentials=credentials, autodiscover=True)

for item in account.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[:100]:
    print(item.subject, item.sender, item.datetime_received)
```